# Style is not applying in custom checkbox and radiobutton

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am developing custom checkbox and radio button but style is not applying for both in pre lollipop devices (Showing black color instead). I have coded like this :

XML :

```
<com.kaho.myapp.CustomCheckBox
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="CheckBoxText"
  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:theme="@style/SampleTheme"/>
```

Custom Checkbox :

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckBox {
    public CustomCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFont(context, attrs) ;
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setFont(context,attrs) ;
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        setFont(context, attrs) ;
    }

    private void setFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            /* Set the font */
        }
    }
}
```

Font in setting properly .
Style :

```
<style name="SampleTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">#08c283</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#969696</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this problem because pre-Lollipop devices don't have the possibility to set a `colorAccent` by default. To obtain a behaviour like this extend your view from the corresponding support view. There would be something like this:

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends AppCompatCheckBox
public class CustomRadioButton extends AppCompatRadioButton
```

In this way, your views will have the material design style on pre Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the custom CheckBox it works great for all version pre/post lollipop.

CustomCheckBox.java:

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckedTextView {
    private Drawable btnDrawable;

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        colorAccordingToTheme();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCheckMarkDrawable(Drawable d) {
        super.setCheckMarkDrawable(d);
        btnDrawable = d;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        super.toggle();
        colorAccordingToTheme();
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        super.setChecked(checked);
        colorAccordingToTheme();
    }

    private void colorAccordingToTheme() {
        if (btnDrawable != null) {
            btnDrawable.setColorFilter(yourColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    }
}
```

In xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.yourpaackcge.CustomCheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/selector_check_box"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"/>
```

My selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_box_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_box_on" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_box_off"/>
</selector>
```